# Maximum valid block size value for DESCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, des

What is a maximum valid `BlockSize` value for `DESCryptoServiceProvider` in .Net 4.0.

I am getting below error for values 32 and 128:

> Not a valid block size

Comment: Can you provide the error message

Comment: "Not a valid block size."

Comment: Your question then should be: What is the accepted block size of DESCryptoServiceProvider :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [`SymmetricAlgorithm.LegalBlockSizes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.legalblocksizes.aspx) property.

It's 64 bits according to the [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.descryptoserviceprovider.aspx) for `DESCrpytoServiceProvider`.